# how to convert any audio file to mp3 in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to upload any audio file and want the out put in the mp3 formate . Is it possible in rails ? Is there ffmpeg code or any thing that convert any audio file to mp3? if any share

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it possible in rails ?

```
Yes it is possible.
```

Is there ffmpeg code or any thing that convert any audio file to mp3?

```
Yes.
```

just follow [this](http://www.danielfischer.com/2007/06/27/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-convert-video-via-ruby-on-rails/) beautiful article

Your command something like follwing

```
system "ffmpeg -i #{full_filename} -r 25 -acodec flv -ar 22050 -y -s 320x240 #{full_filename}.mp3"
```

Comment: @audio_conv = Audio.find(@audio.id)
       
    system "ffmpeg -i #{RAILS_ROOT + '/public' + @audio_conv.public_filename } -r 25 -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 -y -s 320x240 #{RAILS_ROOT + '/public' + @audio_conv.public_filename}.mp3"         
I have tryed this but it shows 
/home/nikhil/sites/musigigs/public/mp3/0000/0016/Airtell.mid: Unknown format
false

Comment: the link is broken...

Answer (score 1):

I used the sox command line utility to convert .ogg files to .mp3 files in my rails app.

```
`sox #{filename + ".ogg"} #{filename + ".mp3"}`
 File.open("#{filename}.mp3")
```

On Mac sox can easily be installed with homebrew

```
brew install sox
```